# stange data/characters below website in browser

Tags: php, html, http, networking, browser

A client of me get this strange block of characters/data below one of my websites. She gets this in different browsers and only with this website. She can't submit a form on the website. Does someone has an idea what's wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: looks like there's a left over print_r or var_dump lying around in a file, of course this is just a stab in the dark, what happens when you visit the same url

Comment: we can't identify the problem without analyzing the code. first you should analyze code and identify where to generate these codes and share these code with stackoverflow users.

Comment: Those look like the server headers. Means that the server is responding using the HTTP protocol version 1.1. 200 is the code used when everything is ok.er.

Comment: It looks like a header and some binary data. I would guess it's gziped (the "Encoding: gzip" gave it away).  You need to show us the code, or it will be impossible for anyone to help.

Answer (score 0):

The strange thing is, she is the only one who gets this from thousands of clients. I suppose the problem lies on her system and not in the code.